# Forcing IE8 Standards Mode with FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Tags: windows-registry, internet-explorer-8, css

I'm doing this:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements)

But it's not working.

I have "iexplore.exe" set to 8888 (decimal mode) under MACHINE, but it's still coming up documentMode = 5.

I thought 8888 was suppose to force IE8 Standards Mode whether you have a doctype or not.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official answer to my question is that it can't be forced.

"you'll see that 8888 mentions that pages are displayed in IE8 Standards Mode (there's a typo though, it just says Internet Explorer 8!) regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive - however, it does not state that pages without a !DOCTYPE are displayed in Standards Mode."

So you have to have a doctype regardless.

Which is irrelevant either way, because selectors simply do not work in IE8 user style sheets applied via Accessibility options, regardless of doctype or document mode.

Fan.Tas.Tic!